# Java & Excel File Creation

Tags: java, apache-poi, exe, executable-jar, jdbc-odbc

I need to create a program to access data from a database and then create an excel sheet of the data retrieved. But I would further like to store/load this excel sheet on the desktop rather than a directory since I would be creating an .exe file of this code.

Comment: Not clear what is your question. If it is how to get the users desktop directory in Java, then this is answered already. Try a research.

Comment: I am gonna create an .exe file , that being said it's going to be an application that may be used on different windows based computers so i need to specify a path that will always save the excel file on the users desktop.

Comment: So you have done a research? https://www.google.de/search?q=how+to+get+the+users+desktop+directory+in+Java

Comment: Yes indeed I have done quite a bit of research. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: @Eterno: if you have done quite a bit of research, you would know how to ask on SO. So you have 3-4 different issues (reading from database, creating an excel sheet, writing to users desktop and in the end it should work as wrapped executable) - you can ask on each of those, but the expectation is, that you are able to combine it yourself and not try to get a full solution on such an issue ...